# Ошибка в асинхронной функции с условием

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

```
app.post('/post',async ({body}, res) => {
    const validatePost = await foo(body)
    const postResult = await foo2(body)

    res.status(200).json(validatePost ? postResult : {success:false})
})
```

foo и foo2 это асинхронные функции.
Проблема в том что foo2 выполняется обходя условие, поэтому когда ей передаются неверные параметры - происходит краш. Насколько я знаю await должно противостоять этому.

Comment: исправил немного, ошибка в именах была

Comment: вот так https://pastebin.com/zjJQUcaT

Comment: Так я тоже могу, но хочется код покороче.

Comment: а вот так - правильнее https://pastebin.com/yHVERmV4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Код покороче - не всегда надежен, к тому же каждый `await` необходимо оборачивать в `try/catch` и выводить ошибки в лог (но не на продакшн). Иначе вы рискуете потерять контекст ошибки, как минимум. Ну и для тестов желательно все кейсы прорабатывать, чтобы потом в продакшене у вас неыбло проблем.

```js
app.post('/post',async ({body}, res) => {
    let validatePost;
    let postResult;

    try {
        validatePost = await foo(body);
    } catch(err) {
        console.error(err);
        res.status(500).json({ success: false });
        return;
    }

    if (!validatePost) {
        res.status(400).json({ success: false });
        return;
    }

    try {
        postResult = await foo2(body);
    } catch(err) {
        console.error(err);
        res.status(500).json({ success: false });
        return;
    }

    res.status(200).json(postResult);
});
```

или так:

```js
class ValidationError extends Error {}

app.post('/post',async ({body}, res) => {
    let postResult;

    try {
        const validatePost = await foo(body);

        if (!validatePost) {
            throw new ValidationError('Some Validation Error');
        }

        postResult = await foo2(body);
    } catch(err) {
        const status = err instanceof ValidationError ? 400 : 500;
        res.status(status).json({ success: false });
        console.error(err);
        return;
    }

    res.status(200).json(postResult);
});
```

Comment: обработчик ошибок выгоднее вынести в экспрессовский миддлваре